# Oracle join to one table OR another

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to accomplish the following:

```
Table: PERSON
OID|NAME
--------
1  |John
2  |Mary

Table: COOL_PERSON
OID|PERSON_OID|...Other columns
--------------------------
5  |1         |...

Table: SMART_PERSON
OID|PERSON_OID|...Other columns
--------------------------
5  |1         |...
```

So, I know that both SMART_PERSON and COOL_PERSON have a PERSON_OID, and a bunch of other columns that are shared in between the two tables. At the moment I have a very large query that is UNIONing the results between those two tables, but what I was wondering is if there is a way to say "join to whichever table the PERSON_OID exists in"? That way I wouldn't have to UNION the exact same query where the only difference is that in one I'm joining to COOL_PERSON and in the other I'm joining to SMART_PERSON. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: `left join` both tables and see which columns are NULL.

Comment: While it can be done, from a DB design perspective this kind of design is going to cause you continual pain as you hit both tables every time, it will be worth reviewing whether you can avoid just a branching of relations in this way.

Comment: Unfortunately, the table design has been in place long before I got here. The query I'm writing is really just a temporary "report". I was just looking at ways to make it less verbose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is two `left join`s:

```
select p.*, coalesce(cp.col1, sp.col1) as col1,
       coalesce(cp.col2, sp.col2) as col2,
       . . .
from person p left join
     cool_person cp
     on p.oid = cp.person_oid left join
     smart_person sp
     on p.oid = sp.person_oid and cp.person_oid is null;
```

This should have better performance than the `union` approach.  However, you should consider fixing your data model.  The common columns should probably go in `person`.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I agree that the data model should be fixed, but that's a bigger fish to fry.